# why this javascript code not executing?

Tags: javascript

i am trying to execute array of objects using **myFunction()** but its not working. what am i missing?? i want to display all objects of array **employees**.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="id01"></div>
<div id="id02"></div>
<script>
myFunction({

"employees":[
   {"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },
   {"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },
   {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }
            ]

});

 function myFunction(employees) {
        var out = "";
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i<employees.length; i++) {
            out += '<a href="' + employees[i].firstName + '">' +
            employees[i].lastName + '</a><br>';
        }
        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    }
    

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `employees` is an object, not an array. The array is in `employees.employees`.

Comment: Don't you see the `{...}` around it, and the `employee:` property? This is basic Javascript syntax.

Comment: yes i can see now. why this code not working??

Comment: The argument you are passing is expected to be an array insead of an object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply pass `array` to the function. You are passing `object` of `employess`

```
<script>
myFunction([
   {"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },
   {"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },
   {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }
            ]

);

 function myFunction(employees) {
        var out = "";
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i<employees.length; i++) {
            out += '<a href="' + employees[i].firstName + '">' +
            employees[i].lastName + '</a><br>';
        }
        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    }


</script>
```

OR if you want to pass `object` of employees you can access like employees.employees

```
myFunction({

        "employees": [
           { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" },
           { "firstName": "Anna", "lastName": "Smith" },
           { "firstName": "Peter", "lastName": "Jones" }
        ]

    });

    function myFunction(employees) {
        var out = "";
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < employees.employees.length; i++) {
            out += '<a href="' + employees.employees[i].firstName + '">' +
            employees.employees[i].lastName + '</a><br>';
        }

        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do what you want :

```
myfunction([
       {"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },
       {"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },
       {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }
                ]);
    function myFunction(employees) {
            var out = "";
            var i;
            for(i = 0; i<employees.length; i++) {
                out += '<a href="' + employees[i].firstName + '">' +
                employees[i].lastName + '</a><br>';
            }
            document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a code snippet for you.

The main problem is that you did not inputed an Array in your function but an object. Also I refactored your code.

```js
var employees = [ {"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" }, {"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" }, {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"} ];

myFunction(employees);

function myFunction(employees) {
  var out = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
    out += '<a href="' + employees[i].firstName + '">' + employees[i].lastName + '</a><br>';
  }
  document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

```html
<div id="id01"></div>
<div id="id02"></div>
```

Sincerly yours